# HTML/CSS - How to get label inside form to animate?

Tags: html, css

I'm watching tutorials on Code School, and there is a tutorial on animating elements via scaling and changing positioning.

The video is on animating a label inside a form. When you focus on the input field, the label (which is inside the input field) moves out of the input field, and scales down in size.

I'm trying to replicate -- with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/8tvh4x45/1/

edit: just want to add that for the transform property, I can get the label to animate if I only have one animation (scale or translateY) -- but I can't get both to work together.

```
<fieldset class="form-field">
  <input class="form-input" type="text" id="name">
  <label class="form-label" for="name">First Name</label>
</fieldset>

.form-field {
  border: 0;
}

.form-input {
  position: absolute;  
}

.form-input + .form-label {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.form-input:focus + .form-label {
  transform: scale(0.8), translateY(50px);
}
```

Comment: you might have luck checking out code here http://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/

Comment: Thank you, i bookmarked the link. a lot of awesome animations there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax for the `transform` property is invalid. When transforming multiple values, they should be separated with spaces (i.e., no commas). [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Formal_syntax) for the formal syntax.

Therefore you need to remove the comma in `transform: scale(0.8), translateY(50px)`.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/4jkar1me/)

```
.form-input + .form-label {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s;
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-input:focus + .form-label {
  transform: scale(0.8) translateY(50px);
}
```

As a side note, in order for this to work across browsers, you may also need to change the `display` of the element to `inline-block` in order for it to be "[transformable](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element)".

According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element):

> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or **atomic inline-level element** (i.e., `inline-block`), or whose display property computes to `table-row`, `table-row-group`, `table-header-group`, `table-footer-group`, `table-cell`, or `table-caption`.